# VS Code - How can I always show open tabs. Multi Line tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to see all my open tabs like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This issue is [still](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70413) being worked on, but should be ready [soon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/106448).

Ctrl+Shift+P, User Settings, Multi Line Tabs

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024/03/30 this is available but there seems to be a bug. To enable multi-line tabs, hit `<Ctrl> + ','` or go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` and  search for "**tabs**". The value `Workbench > Editor: Show Tabs` should be set to **Multiple** and the option `Workbench > Editor: Wrap Tabs` needs to be selected.

VSCode lets you increase/decrease the font size by hitting `<Ctrl> + '+'` and `<Ctrl> + '-'` (also under `View -> Appearance`) and when I did this to "Zoom In" tab wrapping broke. If I reset the view (`<Ctrl> + Numpad'0'`) the multiple tab lines come back, but there does not appear to be a way to make this happen while zoomed.